# My speakers and headphone doesn't work when i connect my headphone to my laptop

Tags: speakers

My speakers work correctly, but whenever I connect headphones to my laptop my headphone doesn't work and if I disconnect headphone speakers doesn't work too, till I restart the laptop
I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop
Please help me ... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this way:

> sudo alsa force-reload 
>   reboot 
>   sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
>   sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
>   sudo alsa force-reload
>   reboot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `alsa`? It's a terminal application that lets you see a list of all audio devices connected to your system. Check if the settings are unchanged when you plug in/out your headphone.[image: alsa-app]

Try pressing F6 to make sure you have selected the current sound card. Also make sure the devices don't get muted.

Comment: yes but when i connect headphone nothing happend